# Drop article from Replication

Tags: sql-server

I have multiple tables with the same name but different schemas.  I want to script out the drop of one of these tables from replication.  I can't find where or how I can declare the schema name.  It only defaults to dbo if I run below

```
EXEC sys.sp_dropsubscription
@publication = 'SGSysTestLVSREP',
@article = 'DropArticleTableName', 
@subscriber = 'Server11', 
@destination_db = 'SysTest'

EXEC sys.sp_droparticle @publication = 'SGSysTestLVSREP',
@article = 'DropArticleTableName',
@force_invalidate_snapshot = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has confirmed that the dbo table is the only table that will be removed.  They recommend writing my own SP

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Remove a table/article from the subscription, go to Publisher properties.
- On the Articles tab, uncheck the tables (schema name are indicated there).
- Click OK then re-run the snapshot replication.

Below are the images for each step:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would like to avoid using the GUI interface.